# Как правильно пользоваться Task в javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть 3 label:

```
@FXML
private Label lbl_days;
@FXML
private Label lbl_time;
@FXML
private Label lbl_times_of_day;
```

И task, который сейчас обновляет текст в lbl_days:

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                boolean running = true;
                double timeSleep;
                updateMessage("Days: " + (game.getHours() / 24));

                while (running) {
                    updateMessage("Days: " + (game.getHours() / 24));
                    timeSleep = NORMAL_SPEED / speed;
                    Thread.sleep((long) timeSleep);
                    if (isRunning)
                        game.increaseHours();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        lbl_days.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());

        new Thread(task).start();
```

Мне нужно в этом же task`е обновлять текст и других label`ов. 
Как это можно сделать?
Зарание спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое что приходит в голову:

```
while (running) {
//    updateMessage("Days: " + (game.getHours() / 24));

    //updateMessage делает почти тоже самое
    Platform.runLater( () -> {
        lbl_days.setText( "Days: " + (game.getHours() / 24) );
        lbl_time.setText( /*?*/ );
        lbl_times_of_day.setText( /*?*/ );
    } );
    ...
}
```

Можно завести свою проперть:

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
     public LongProperty hours = new SimpleLongProperty();

     @Override
     protected Void call() throws InterruptedException {
         ...
         while (running) {
         Platform.runLater( () -> {
             hours.set( game.getHours() );
         } );
     ...  
     }
     ...
}

task.hours.addListener( ( ov, oldV, newV ) -> {
    lbl_days.setText( "Days: " + (newV / 24) );
    lbl_time.setText( /*?*/ );
    lbl_times_of_day.setText( /*?*/ );
} );
```

Можно это же время строкой писать в `updateMessage()` и парсить слушателем, но это как-то нехорошо.

И мне кажется `Task` здесь вообще избыточен и можно использовать `java.uti.concurrent.Executor`, но я могу ошибаться.